# MathJax flickering and statusbar showing in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, equation, mathjax

for a school project, we were supposed to make a simple calculator. The project's goal was to teach github, teamwork, testing, documentation, and all that jazz. It is not really about the calculator. However, my team and I decided to take it a step further and we wanted to create a calculator that displays mathematical expressions in real time.

I managed to find a way: using PyQt5 and its QWebEngineView, I was able to display a simple webpage, and, using javascript, I was able to display an equation in real time using MathJax. However, there are some problems:

Upon entering any number, first, a statusbar appears (for a split second) on the lower part of the display like this:

[image]

Bu that is not all - before the final number appears, first, a raw latex code is shown for a fraction of a second, then a HTMLPreview version of the fraction, and only after all this does the final render appear.

This is the python x javascript part:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Ui_s_cals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content=["10","+","10"]

    def setupUi(self, s_cals):
        s_cals.setObjectName("s_cals")
        s_cals.resize(300, 500)
        s_cals.setWindowTitle("Calculator")

        self.display = QWebEngineView(s_cals)
        self.display.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 300, 60))
        self.pushButton_n0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(s_cals)
        self.pushButton_n0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 400, 61, 61))
        self.pushButton_n0.setObjectName("pushButton_n0")
        self.pushButton_n0.setText("0")
        self.pushButton_n0.clicked.connect(lambda:self.print("0"))

    def print(self,number):
        self.content.append(number)
        print(self.content)
        #self.output1.setText(''.join(self.content))
        temp=''.join(self.content)
        self.expression=temp
        self.pageSource = '''
                                <html><head>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">                     
                                </script></script><script>MathJax.Hub.Config({{
jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
displayAlign: "left"
}});</script>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                <p><mathjax style="font-size:1em">$${expression}$$</mathjax></p>
                                </body></html>
                                '''.format(expression=self.expression)
        self.display.setHtml(self.pageSource)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_s_cals()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

def main():
    calc = QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = Main()
    sys.exit(calc.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    print(time.time() - start)
```

I was looking for answers for hours. I tried setting the visibility of body to hidden, and then making it visible by a script after mathjax is done rendering, but it didn't work.

I tried all the answers on stack overflow, but none of them counted on me using this inside a python script, which might be the problem. if you know a different way of showing equations in real time.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you for your answer, I added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change whole page content to render new expression, instead you can use `QWebEnginePage.runJavaScript` method. Look at [input-tex2chtml.html](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web/blob/master/input-tex2chtml.html) example in [MathJax-demos-web](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-web)

Demo:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>MathJax v3 with interactive TeX input and HTML output</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>
  <script>
    function convert(input) {
      output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.innerHTML = '';
      MathJax.texReset();
      var options = MathJax.getMetricsFor(output);
      options.display = true;
      MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise(input, options).then(function (node) {
        output.appendChild(node);
        MathJax.startup.document.clear();
        MathJax.startup.document.updateDocument();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
      });
    }
  </script>
  <style>
  body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #output {
    font-size: 120%;
    min-height: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
  }
  .right {
    float: right;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="output" class="left"></div>
</body>
</html>
"""

class Window_Ui:
    def setupUi(self, widget):
        view = QWebEngineView()
        edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(view)
        layout.addWidget(edit)
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.view = view
        self.edit = edit

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ui = Window_Ui()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self._ui = ui
        ui.view.setHtml(html)
        page = ui.view.page()
        page.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        ui.edit.setText("{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}")
        ui.edit.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self._ready = False

    def onLoadFinished(self):
        if self._ready:
            return
        self._ready = True
        self.onTextChanged(self._ui.edit.text())

    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        ui = self._ui
        text = text.replace("\\","\\\\")
        page = ui.view.page()
        page.runJavaScript('convert("{}");'.format(text))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(300,150)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; the script source link you provided, however, does not allow me to align the equations to the left. Or right. Do you know any way for me to align the output text? It is always centered if I use text-align: left in the div, and when I use the Mathjax Hub align script as I used in my original post, nothing happens. So, please, if you know of a way to align this equation to either side, I would be grateful.

Comment: @ampersander you can align equation using css float property, with inline style or with css class, I updated the code